# How to forcefully load viewcontroller in portrait mode when we are in landscape mode. When drilling back the view should return back to landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an issue.
I want to load a view-controller forcefully in portrait mode if we are in landscape mode and when we drill back, the previous view-controller should be loaded in landscape mode.
Please help.
I have added link which has screenshots for this issue.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0VhXuZwbqnsUE5GcmVqcnJLeFU&usp=sharing

Comment: do you want a particular view in Portrait mode when you go to that view?

Comment: @Manthan: Yes, the view has to be in portrait. We will be drilling from view which is in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ;
}
```

You will have to lock the interfaceorientation as per your needs.